# snap.svg, just started, can't get anything working

Tags: svg, snap.svg

as said in the topic title I just got started with snap.svg this morning following [this tutorial](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-manipulate-and-animate-svg-with-snapsvg--cms-21323). I think I followed every step the right way but in the end I can't display anything in my browser.

What I did :

1 - Create "snap" folder on desktop

2 - Create "js" folder inside the "snap" folder

3 - Create snap.html file in "snap" folder

4 - Create main.js in "js" folder

5 - Download snap.svg.js and add it to "js" folder

6 - Wrote this in my snap.html :

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="js/snap.svg.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <svg id="svg1"></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

7 - And wrote this in my main.js :

```
var s = Snap("#svg1");
var r = s.circle(50,50,25);
```

This should be the most basic of snap.svg but I couldn't even make it work, I'm a bit ashamed but I prefere to come and ask you guys for guidance before plugging my hair out one by one...
Thank you !

Comment: Press F12 in your browser to bring up the developer tools.  Switch to the "Console" tab in the dev tools. Are you getting any error messages printed there?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the DOM isn't ready when your JS is run.  That is because your JS is in the `<head>` of your HTML.

There are two solutions.  Move the `<script>` elements to the bottom of your HTML so they are loaded later.

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <svg id="svg"></svg>
  <script src="js/snap.svg.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or alternatively you can make sure your JS doesn't run until the DOM is ready.  You can do that by employing one of several methods.

For instance, you can put your code into a window onload event:

```
window.onload = function() {

  var s = Snap("#svg1");
  var r = s.circle(50,50,25);

};
```

Or if you are planning on using jQuery, you could use its `ready()` function, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I would have raged quite a lot before finding this one! You saved half of my remaining neurons !